# How do i show the list of items which belong to the same category using Django Python?

Tags: python, django, url, orm

I have Shop page and it displays list of shops when i click on one shop i want the other page to display the related list of products for that page only.

```
def shop_products(request, id):
    shops = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products/shop_products.html', {'shops': shops})
```

> path

```
  path('products/<int:id>', views.shop_products, name='shop-products'),

   <a href="{% url 'shop-products' product.id %}" class="grey-text"> The clickable link
```

Using the above code it is displaying all the products of every shop

Comment: you're talking about shops and products but in your code you're mixing them all around the place. Are those different things or the same thing? What are your models? If your page is supposed to show all the products belonging to one specific shop, why do you pass a `product.id` to the url and not a `shop.id`?

Comment: Actually i hace been modifying the variable names so it has created confusion. What you have mentioned above is actually correct. Could you give an idea in this.

Comment: Then the url should be `{% url 'shop-product' shop.id %}` and in your view, you would get the products for the shop with `products = Product.objects.filter(shop_id=id)` assuming your `Product` model has a FK to `Shop` calls `shop`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are ignoring `product.id`. You should filter for it:

```
def shop_products(request, id):
    shops = Product.objects
    if id:
        shops = shops.filter(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'products/shop_products.html', {'shops': shops.all()})
```

I'm a bit confused because of `shops = Product` - are shops the same as products for you?